# Livewire 3 Property reset method not working

Tags: laravel-livewire

```
`$this->reset() `method not working with while i am using livewire 3`


    .blade.php file

<div class="flex items-center justify-center">
    <form class="mt-6 space-y-2 border-t-2 border-slate-800 px-4 py-4 shadow">
        <input class="block rounded-md border border-slate-800 px-2 py-1" type="text" placeholder="name"
            wire:model='name'>
        <input class="block rounded-md border border-slate-800 px-2 py-1" type="email" placeholder="email..."
            wire:model='email'>
        <input class="block rounded-md border border-slate-800 px-2 py-1" type="password" placeholder="password"
            wire:model='password'>
        <button class="rounded-md bg-slate-800 px-4 py-2 text-white" type="submit"
            wire:click.prevent="store">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>`
```

here livewire component code on server side $this->reset(['name','email','password']) is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you show us your Livewire component's code? Do you get an error calling `$this->reset()`? How/where are you calling it? Show us that code.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem recently, and its most probably because you initialized alpine separately in app.js file. Livewire V3 now includes Alpine bundled in, so you will need to remove the Alpine setup code from app.js.

```
import './bootstrap';


// remove the below alpine setup lines


/* import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start(); */
```

Reference: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/6805

Answer (score -1):

declare a public property like:

public $isDisable = true;

now use this property in your blade file
<button {{$isDisable?'disable':''}}>submit

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all.